# "sudo -l" not working

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, 20.10

Using Ubuntu 20.10.
But when i run command `sudo -l` the terminal shows me this error:

```
bardia@bardia-Rajabi-Ubuntu:~$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for bardia: 
Matching Defaults entries for bardia on bardia-Rajabi-Ubuntu:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User bardia may run the following commands on bardia-Rajabi-Ubuntu:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Also i dont want to make my system run sudo without any password: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-running-sudo-command-without-a-password/
Edit:After this massage shows up the command doesn't work.

Comment: Hi I do not see an error I see an information message. Does something you want to do not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest assured. The `sudo -l` command lists allowed and forbidden commands for the user that invokes the command.

Typically, authorized users can run all commands, which also is indicated in your output. That output is perfectly normal and does not contain any error messages at all.

Comment: But in past the sudo -l command didnt show me this massage and work properly.

Comment: Also sudo "command" work properly.

Comment: That is what I indicated. Please accept my answer if it helped you. I cannot help you with how it worked in past versions. You are in 20.10, and that is how it works normally in this version.

Comment: Wait i just started using ubuntu from version 20.10 this is first version of ubuntu that im using!

Comment: Something unclear in my answer?

Comment: Yes you said the past versions but this is the only version that im using

Comment: I did not place that in my answer. I now saw you do need to provide your user password also, so I deleted the info this would also work as normal user (when I checked, my password likely was still cached from a previous sudo command).